# HAML 6: Replacement or alternative for haml_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

In upgrading an older Rails app to the latest and greatest versions of everything, I've discovered that the `haml_tag` helper method was removed from Haml::Helpers in version 6. A quick grep of the haml and haml-rails sources reveal that there are no references to it (other than the changelog noting its removal).

haml_tag lets you generate output with an arbitrary tag name, attributes, and content, like this:

```
- tag_name = my_content_model.tag_name || "section"  # something dynamic
- haml_tag(tag_name, {attr: value, attr2: value2}) do
    %div.inner
        %h2 Contents go here.
```

I make heavy use of haml_tag in a CMS where users can pick a tag name for their blocks of content, and would prefer not to have to redesign that feature. Is there an adequate replacement for it, perhaps in a third-party library?

(For now I have my Gemfile locking HAML to version 5)

Answer (score 5):

It seems like the answer here is to change calls from `haml_tag` to `content_tag` when using haml v6.

- https://github.com/k0kubun/hamlit/issues/73
- https://github.com/k0kubun/hamlit/issues/71